# Cookie is created by which and how?

Tags: cookies, nginx, php

I am using nginx, php-fpm.

I want to know 
which process is in charge of creating cookie?

and where the cookie file is saved on server?

Can scripting language like php change where it's saved on the fly?

```
root     10696  0.0  0.1  45240  3232 ?        Ss    2012   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
www      14616  0.0  0.1  45240  3164 ?        S    18:00   0:00 nginx: worker process
root     10517  0.0  0.3 228960  7584 ?        Ss   Mar06   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.conf)       
www      11450  0.0  1.4 247772 28948 ?        S    Mar06   0:51 php-fpm: pool www                                               
www      11471  0.0  1.8 252888 35876 ?        S    Mar06   0:50 php-fpm: pool www                                               
www      14268  0.1  1.7 250200 33140 ?        S    16:52   0:30 php-fpm: pool www                                               
root     15566  0.0  0.0  61296   764 pts/2    S+   23:11   0:00 grep php
```

Answer (score 1):

First off cookies are not stored on the server. Cookies are stored on the Users PC. Sessions on the other hand are saved on the server. You can find where they are stored by checking your php.ini file and look for a setting called session.save_path

As for which process, it will be the one for which the script was called on. This is pretty much not able to be traced.